# How to handle SceneDelegate willConnectTo method in new SwiftUIApp lifecycle

Tags: swiftui

How do I handle this method in new SwiftUI app lifecycle?
I am looking at the Scene but it does not have any  info about SceneDelegate methods

`func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { method in SwiftUI new App cycle.`

Comment: There is no SceneDelegate in SwiftUI life cycle. Why do you need it? What do you want to do?

Comment: For the remote notification. I am handing the remote notification in this method when the app is not running and is launched from the notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get notified when a device receives a specific notification using `.onReceive` modifier.
for your case, you can use `.onReceive` like this on top of one of your view(s) to get notified for scene connections:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIScene.willConnectNotification)) { notification in
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get notification through `userNotificationCenter` even when the app is not running and is launched from the notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("open notification")
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
```